# Vue v-model.lazy or @change does not update my Vue data

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

With chrome build in voice recognition I change the textarea value with spoken words. After the value changes, my vue data does not update.

I already tried v-model.lazy, @change and v:bind.

**Vue template**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea v-model.lazy="textboxInput" contenteditable="true" @change="onDivInput($event) " class="form-control" id="result" rows="1" name="inputData"></textarea>
 </div>
```

**Vue code**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            result: [],
            textboxInput: '',
            session_id: this.sessionid,
            user: this.userid,
            edit: false,
            roundRobin: JSON.parse(this.roundrobin),
        }
    },
    props: {
        sessionid: '',
        userid: '',
        roundrobin: '',

    },
    mounted() {
        this.getResult();
        this.listen();
        this.mod();

    },


    methods: {
        onDivInput: function (e) {

            this.textboxInput = e.target.innerHTML;
            console.log(e);
        },
```

**Javascript where textarea value changes
R is the textarea**

```
try {
    let finalTranscripts = '';
    if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window && hasUserMedia) {
        let speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        speechRecognizer.continuous = false;
        speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
        speechRecognizer.lang = 'nl-be';
        speechRecognizer.start();



        speechRecognizer.onresult = function (event) {
            let interimTranscripts = '';
            for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
                let transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
                if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                    finalTranscripts += transcript;
                } else {
                    interimTranscripts += transcript;
                }
            }
            r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + interimTranscripts;


        }


        ;
        speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {
            speechRecognizer.stop();
        };
    } else {
        r.innerHTML = 'Your browser is not supported. If google chrome, please upgrade!';
    }
} catch (ex) {
    e.innerHTML = ex;
}
```

*If the innerhtml of the textarea changes i want that my data updates aswell.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Docs on v-model.lazy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy)

> By default, v-model syncs the input with the data after each input event (with the exception of IME composition as stated above). You can add the lazy modifier to instead sync after change events.

Right now you're using both v-model.lazy (which syncs after change events) and @change (which, whats in the name, also listens to change events). That's one too many. `v-model.lazy="textboxInput"` is actually a shortcode for `:value="textboxInput" @change="textboxInput = $event.target.value"`. So you're  actually listening to @change twice.

You can just use

```
    <textarea v-model.lazy="textboxInput" contenteditable="true" class="form-control" id="result" rows="1" name="inputData"></textarea>
```

Which already syncs the value of e.target.value back to your prop.

If you want to 'textboxInput` to listen to input, you should remove the .lazy modifier.

Comment: I used it. But after the javascript changes the innerHTML, it won't change my data. If I write myself in the textarea then my data property changes. It won't fire the @change function either after I recorded something :(

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your issue there. You shouldn't manipulate the DOM outside of Vue.  Best approach here imo is to rewrite your transcript JS to directly change `textboxInput`

Comment: @Frank thank you for your awesome answer. In my case, $event.traget.value does not work for me, but when I use $event my code works perfectly?

Comment: @KickButtowski It's quite an old answer and I haven't been using Vue much ever since, but that totally depends on the data that is emitted.  If you install vue devtools then you can inspect the value of $event.